# TestCafe-How to reload page repeatly

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Currently,I've used `await t.eval(() => location.reload(true));` to hard reload page,works fine if just do once,but in some page(private page,I'm still seeking for the public page sample),it pops out some error like so:

```
An error occurred in eval code:

Failed to set a named property on 'Storage'
```

or something like this:

```
QuotaExceededError: Failed to set a named property on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'hammerhead|storage-wrapper|GWAW6stQj|mypage.com' exceeded the quota.
```

*Note the mypage.com is just an url used to replace

I've serach for document about this situation,some said that the `Qouta` issue can be avoid by clear the localstorage,but didn't work for me.
How should I reload the page repeatly without getting those errors?I'm using Chrome 113.0.0.0 / Windows 10,thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, your approach with `t.eval` is correct. It does not look like a TestCafe issue. As a workaround, you can try using the `--native-automation` flag ([https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode)). If this does not help, please share the public example.